# Change user role after bulk-import

Tags: user-roles

after successful import of ~4000 users and their blogs & posts from Liftype I have a rights problem: all users only are subscribers in their own blog. How can I mass change it to blog (not sitewide!) administrator privileges? All known functions I found in Codex gives Admin rights for the main blog, that's not what I want.

Thanks
Uwe

Edit:
What's wrong here?

```
include 'wp-load.php';
global $wpdb;
for ( $blog_id = 393; $blog_id <=4091; $blog_id++ ){

  $bloguser= get_users_of_blog ($blog_id);
    foreach ($bloguser as $usr) { // maybe there is more than one
        $user_id = $usr->ID;
          echo 'Blog No. '.$blog_id.' is property of user: '.$user_id;  //control check
      if ($user_id != '') {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user->for_blog($blog_id);
        $user->remove_role('editor');
        $user->add_role('administrator');
      }
    }
}
echo 'Done!';
```

Code is well running, but there is no change to user's role.

Edit: code typo edited, no changes to result

@EAMann Are you sure, add_role is the right function? I understand this is for adding a new role to WP system.

Edit: Updated the code again. Using update_user_meta. $check gives back 'administrator' (right!), but if I call the user's blog properties, the user is always 'editor'.

Comment: As I mentioned below, make sure you use `$user->remove_role('subscriber')` otherwise they'll be both an admin *and* a subscriber ... which isn't the functionality you want.

Comment: OK, if the user is an "Editor", then use `$user->remove_role('editor');` ... you need to remove their current role so that their *only* role is administrator.  And yes, I'm sure this is the right function - see the inline documentation of the function in the [WP_User](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L558) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I'm assuming these are users on a specific blog within a MultiSite installation, correct?  In that case, do the following:

1. Go to the blog for which you want to make these users administrators.
2. Click on the "Users" button in the left-side admin sidebar

   - This will present you with a display of about 20 users at a time (the display is paged)
3. Click the checkbox next to the users you wish to promote
4. At the top of the list is a dropdown box that says "Change role to..." - Select "Administrator" from this select box
5. Click the "Change" button to the right of the select box

You'll have to do this for each page of users, and with 4000 users you'll have about 160 pages of results.  But it's doable.

---

## Update

If you want some specific code, I recommend looking at the [`WP_User`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L363) class.  This class defines two methods that you'd need to use iteratively: `for_blog()` and `add_role()`.

Basically, you'll need to loop through your users based either on their IDs or usernames.  Consider this ***untested*** example code:

```
$ids = [1,2,3,4];
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $user = new WP_User($id);
    $user->for_blog( ... user's blog id ... );
    $user->remove_role('subscriber');
    $user->add_role('administrator');
}
```

By default, the `add_role()` method of the `WP_User` class will act on the current blog ... you use `for_blog()` to switch to a specific blog before running the `add_role()` method.

So if you have the ids of your users and the ids of the blogs they're supposed to be administrators for, you can loop through them pretty easily and set them up as administrators for their specific sites.

Comment: Thank you but this solves not my problem. Yes it's a multisite installation. Every user has one own blog, every blog has one user. But after import, he can only write and edit his articles, not administrate the blog settings. After import, new registered users have the role administrator, all the imported users are only subscribers for their blog. Maybe there is a WP function like set_user_role_for_blog ($user_id; $blog_id; $role) (example for understanding) I can run once. AFAIK is this information in usermeta? Has anyone a code for direct DB change?

Comment: Please see my update for an example with code ...

Comment: What's wrong here? 
[code]include 'wp-load.php';
global $wpdb;
for ( $blog_id = 393; $blog_id <=400; $blog_id++ ){ //limited for testing

  $bloguser= get_users_of_blog ($blog_id);
    foreach ($bloguser as $usr) { // maybe there is more than one
        $user_id = $usr->ID;
          echo 'Blog No. '.$blog_id.' is property of user: '.$user_id.'<br />';  //control check
      if (!$user_id == '') {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user->for_blog($blog_id);
        $user->add_role('administrator');
      }
    }
}
echo 'Done!';
[/code]
There is no change to user's role.

Comment: **@Uwe** your code is unreadable in a comment.  Please amend your original question so we can read what you're doing.

Comment: Very quick response thx. Post is edited.

Comment: You need to remove the role of 'subscriber' first.  I just tested this and it works, and I've updated by answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have edited the code above for the last time into the working one. All users are converted.
I wish you a merry christmas!

Comment: Please remember to mark this as "the" answer by clicking the green checkmark if it worked for you :-)  Merry Christmas!

Comment: Looking at the `WP_User` class i'd have thought the `for_blog` method call, `$user->for_blog($blog_id);` should occur after you've changed the user's role. Take a look at what the method does and see if you agree - be curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: No, I disagree. `for_blog($blog_id)` sets the ID of the blog you're working with. So if you're on `$blog_id=1` and you run `add_role()` for a user, you're setting their role *on blog 1*.  If you are on blog 1 and you want to set a particular user's role on blog 23, you'll need to run `$user->for_blog(23);` *first* before you try setting their role.  This allows you to set the roles of users for blogs other than the one you're currently on.